# How to map json object in React with useState, useEffect and axios auth?

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

My goal is to map an array within a json object I'm calling from my API call with `axios` and `fetchContext` I had written for passing headers.

My problem, I can console.log the data but whenever I try to return the results array I get no list items.

My json from the `console.log` to get the `results` array:

```
{count: 4, results: Array(4)}
count: 4
results: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

My ReactJS Component:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FetchContext } from '../context/FetchContext';

export const RandomPage = () => {
  const fetchContext = useContext(FetchContext);
  const [bookData, setBookData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get('/dummylibrary/book/');

        setBookData(data.bookData);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    getData();
  }, [fetchContext.authAxios]);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {bookData &&
          bookData.map((book) => (
            <li key={book.id}>
              {book.id}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

What did I miss or am not calling correctly in my React Component?  My apologies in advance if this is a repeat, the answers out there didn't quite match up.

Comment: It's `data.results`. setJobData(data.results);

Comment: `data.bookData` is undefined in your response `data` object. It should be `setJobData(data.results);` instead. The `bookData &&` condition is masking the undefined state value, you can, and probably should, remove this extra condition since `.map` can handle empty arrays. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo".

Comment: yep those are correct, I was missing my `data.results`. Too much coffee today.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `data.results` in my setBookData.  Thank you @Naren and @Drew Reese.